# Switch to Switch - Transfer user with Breath of the Wild DLC Saves to new Switch?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, nintendo-switch

I have an existing Switch console with 2 users saved data on it.

On the original console user 1 has purchased the Breath of the Wild DLC.

The second user has used the Breath of the Wild DLC and has a full set of saved data for the DLC.

We purchased a new Nintendo Switch console for X-Mas and want to move the second user over to the new console.

I have no problem with purchasing the DLC again for the new Nintendo Switch console.

The question I have is: If I transfer user 2 from the old Switch console to the new Switch console do they lose all their DLC game saves?

Comment: One way you might be able to test this is delete the DLC and try playing the save that contains DLC content.  This in essence would be like playing on the new Switch that doesn't contain the DLC yet. Beware though, I have no idea what this may do to your save data. My guess is it won't let you load the save or it will let you play it but remove anything you've obtained from the DLC.

Comment: Thanks @TimmyJim! This is a great idea. If it was my saved game data, I would give it a go. However, I am really afraid of doing that, the last thing I need is a totally downtrodden 12 year old in the house.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you transfer your user data all of your saves in any games will transfer over unless you do something wrong during the transfer.